# Filter Rows with time difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a "readings" table with columns

1. `timestamp` as DateTime
2. `channel_id` as integer
3. `value` as Decimal
4. `test_id` as integer

Now i want to filter rows by `test_id` which anybody can do. Then in the result number of rows is too much. Suppose if i use `channel number 2,3 and 5` for my `test_id 17` and if I log data for every second then there are **10k** rows.

When I plot the graph there where will so many data that the graph lines are not visible clearly, so to make them visible I need to filter out some rows.

I need some help in filtering of rows with time difference between the two records should be few seconds lets say 10 seconds. In this the data is not consecutive.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The sample data will be as follows:

```
24-05-2016 08:00:55 am | 2 | 10.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:55 am | 3 | 100.23 | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:55 am | 5 | 12.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:56 am | 2 | 09.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:56 am | 3 | 12.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:56 am | 5 | 11.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:57 am | 2 | 09.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:57 am | 3 | 01.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:57 am | 5 | 11.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:58 am | 2 | 09.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:58 am | 3 | 01.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:58 am | 5 | 11.23  | 17
```

Comment: So what's your expected result?

Comment: What would be the result from your sample data? There is no 10sec difference between any of then.

Comment: if i want rows with time difference of 2 sec or more the data will be available for each `channel 2,3, and 5` and first data starts at 24-05-2016 08:00:55 am, next data will be at 24-05-2016 08:00:57 am again for all channels 2,3 and 5.

Comment: The expected result is as below...  If i want rows with timedifference of 2sec or more the result woulbe `code` 24-05-2016 08:00:55 am | 2 | 10.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:55 am | 3 | 100.23 | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:55 am | 5 | 12.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:57 am | 2 | 09.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:57 am | 3 | 01.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:57 am | 5 | 11.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:59 am | 2 | 09.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:59 am | 3 | 01.23  | 17

24-05-2016 08:00:59 am | 5 | 11.23  | 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filtering you can aggregate data for the period using GROUP BY functionality. For example, 10-second periods can be calculated from the timestamps using this formula:

```
ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/10)
```

So, this formula can be added to GROUP BY query, so query can aggregate data on that period:

```
SELECT test_id,channel_id,ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/10),
    min(value), max(value), avg(value),count(*)
FROM your_table
WHERE some_conditions
GROPU BY test_id,channel_id,ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/10)
```

Comment: Great @amaksr. 99.99% my problem is solved except when i try for 10 seconds period it gives me data of 8 seconds period. my data starts at `2016-05-24 14:51:37` so next data should be at 10 seconds or more but not before that so it makes `2016-05-24 14:51:47` or later but it shows data for `2016-05-24 14:51:45` and skips data at `2016-05-24 14:51:47`

Comment: your solution works for some querries. If i want data at 2 sec periods it gives me unwanted rows too. Any possibility of improvement ?